# FOSRestBundle FormType convert JsonArray to ArrayCollection

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hello im currently creating a Rest Api and I want to receive something like this:

```
{"collection": [1,2,3]}
```

I have come up with something like this:

```php
    public function postDTOAction(Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createForm(DTOType::class);
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return $this->view($form->getData());
        }

        return  $this->view($form);
    }

class DTO {
   public ArrayCollection $collection;
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->collection = new ArrayCollection();
   }
}

class DTOType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('collection');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => DTO::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ]);

    }
}
```

somehow this doesnt seem to work and im getting the error that `collection` is a invalid type.

Answer (score 0):

Chaning My DTO to (replacing ArrayCollection with a plain array)

```php
class DTO {
   public array $collection;
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->collection = [];
   }
}
```

and adding

```php
$builder->add('collection', CollectionType::class, ['allow_add' => true]);
```

solved my problem.